# Video capture by FFMPEG with closed captions data

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, closed-captions

I'm trying to capture TV broadcasting from Avermedia C027 card using FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg -y -re -rtbufsize 500M -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 29.97 -f dshow -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\pci#ven_1a0a&dev_6202&subsys_620f1461&rev_01#4&3227f04d&0&00d8#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\{ede957b0-eaa5-4bf4-acf3-6e10cb4836c3}":audio="@device_pnp_\\?\pci#ven_1a0a&dev_6202&subsys_620f1461&rev_01#4&3227f04d&0&00d8#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\{ca465100-deb0-4d59-818f-8c477184adf6}" -c:v h264 -c:a aac -f mpegts test.ts
```

Video and audio is OK, but captured video does not contain EIA-608 closed captions data. I tried to add [out0+subcc] flag after video device name, but FFMPEG says that device name is incorrect in this case.

Video data of Avermedia card undoubtly contain closed captions, because another software installed to the computer can capture video with closed captions.

Is there any flags to tell to FFMPEG that closed captions should be captured with video?

Comment: If you just copy the H.264 stream instead of re-encoding it, would the CCs be saved? I think so. Once you have a copy of the stream that contains the CC data, you should be able to copy it with a tool like https://www.ccextractor.org. (I haven't tested that tool, but it came up in a search and looks promising.)

Answer (score 2):

Encoding EIA-608 captions into the video file has been an outstanding feature request for some time. There is currently an open issue for adding support to ffmpeg and it has not yet been addressed.

This request comes up on mailings list frequently, but there doesn't seem to be a timeline for adding support.

[EIA-608 / EIA-708 Closed Captions disappear when transcoding/reencoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1778#comment:10)

Comment: Thank you for explanations.
FFMPEG cannot encode EIA-608 closed caption into video file, but maybe there is some way to write subtitles from captured data into separate SRT file?